# why is react-redux wrapping connected components within Memo

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I upgraded the package react-redux from version: 6.0.1 to version: 7.2.3
along with types to the latest version: 7.1.16.

I observed all my snapshot stored are failing incase of redux connected *class based components* :

original snapshot:

```
<Connect(DynamicElements) />
```

new snapshot:

```
<Memo(Connect(DynamicElements)) />
```

- I tried official docs to get knowledge on what Memo does to the connected components but did not find any answer. (from the name Memo its clear that it would be helping in preventing re-renders)
- Is the addition of Memo any issue or should I accept the new snapshot as is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure connect in older versions would produce a pure component so they would not re render unless you pass in different props or mapStateToProps/useSelector callback returns a different value. The behaviour should not have changed but the implementation did, since 7.0.0 [hooks were used](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/1209). It is better to be safe than sorry so if you have the snapshot files in your git repo you should be ok adopting the new nesting.

Comment: I think they changed the implementation [in this commit](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/1209/commits/c31b94a9495c25000e00fcb63397aa233236af3a) replacing PureComponent with React.memo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-Redux has *always* implemented `connect` to act similar to a "pure/memoized component", so that your own wrapped component only re-renders if the resulting "child props" (combined props from `mapState`, `mapDispatch`, and the parent) have changed.

*How* we've implemented that has changed over time, based on several factors.

In React-Redux v7, we specifically chose to use [`React.memo()` HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) as the method for doing some of that comparison work.

For more details, see my extensive post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/), which talks about the changes to our implementation approach over the years.